# Заменить элемент в LinkedList c#

Tags: c#, list, linked-list

реализовываю свой LinkedList на С# и для решения определенной задачи, мне нужно реализовать метод Replace(), который будет заменять один елемент на другой

```
public void Replace(T target, Item<T> to_replace)
{
    if (to_replace == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(to_replace));
    }
    var current = _head;
        
    Item<T> previous = null;
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.Data.Equals(target))
        {
            current = new Item<T>(target);
            if (previous != null)
            {
                previous.Next = to_replace;
            }
            else
            {
                _head = to_replace;
            }
            break;
        }
        current = previous.Next;
    }

}
```

to_replace заменяет все элементы списка, и он остается один. Почему так?
сам код

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private Item<T> _head = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Крайній елемент списка
    /// </summary>
    private Item<T> _tail = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Кількість елементів у списку
    /// </summary>
    private int _count = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Геттер для Count
    /// </summary>
    public int Count
    {
        get => _count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Додамо дані в список
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    public void Add(T data)
    {
        // Перевіряємо вхідні дані
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
        }

        // Створюємо новий елемент списка
        var item = new Item<T>(data);

        // Якщо список порожній, то кладемо його на початок
        // якщо ні, додаємо цей елемент як наступний за останнім елементом
        if (_head == null)
        {
            _head = item;
        }
        else
        {
            _tail.Next = item;
        }

        // Встановлюємо цей елемент останнім
        _tail = item;

        // Ітерація змінної, яка містить кількість елементів у списку
        _count++;
    }
    public void Replace(T target, Item<T> to_replace)
    {
        if (to_replace== null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(to_replace));
        }
        var current = _head;
            
        Item<T> previous = null;
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Data.Equals(target))
            {
                if (previous != null)
                {
                    previous.Next = to_replace;
                }
            }
            current = previous.Next;
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Видалити дані із списку
    /// Виконується видалення першого входження даних
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">Дані, які будуть видалені </param>
    public void Delete(T data)
    {
        // Перевіряємо вхідні дані
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
        }

        // Теперішній елемент
        var current = _head;

        // Попередній елемент
        Item<T> previous = null;

        // Проходимося по всіх елементах списка до його завершення,
        // або поки не буде знайдено елемент, який потрібно видалити
        while (current != null)
        {
            // Якщо дані теперішнього елемента співпадають з даними, які потрібно видалити
            // то видаляємо теперішній елемент, враховуючи його розташування в ланцюку.
            if (current.Data.Equals(data))
            {
                // Якщо елемент знаходиться в середині або кінці списка,
                // викидаємо теперішній елемент зі списка
                // якщо це перший елемент списка, то викидаємо його
                if (previous != null)
                {
                    // Встановлюємо у попереднього елемента вказівник на наступний елемент від теперішнього.
                    previous.Next = current.Next;

                    // Якщо це був останній елемент списка,
                    // то змінюємо вказівник на крайній елемент списка
                    if (current.Next == null)
                    {
                        _tail = previous;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // встановлюємо "головний" елемент наступним.
                    _head = _head.Next;

                    // Якщо список порожній,
                    // то обнуляємо і крайній елемент.
                    if (_head == null)
                    {
                        _tail = null;
                    }
                }

                // Елемент видалений
                // Зменшуємо кількість елементів на одиницю і виходимо з циклу.
                // Для того, щоб видалити всі входження даних із списка,
                // потрібно не виходити із циклу, а дати йому дійти до кінця..
                _count--;
                break;
            }

            // Переходимо до наступного елемента
            previous = current;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Очистимо список 
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        _head = null;
        _tail = null;
        _count = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Повернути ітератор,який перебирає всі елементи в списку.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> Ітератор, який можна використати для ітерації по колекції. </returns>
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Перебираємо всі елементи списка, для представлення у виді колекції елементів.
        var current = _head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Data;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Повернути ітератор, який виконує ітераційний перехід по списку
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> Об'єкт IEnumerator, який використовується для проходження по колекції. </returns>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Повертаємо ітератор, який визначений вище.
        // Для реалізації інтерфейсу IEnumerable
        // для того , щоб можна було використовувати foreach
        return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Item<T> previous = null;` и далее вы не меняете значение `previous`. А вот в методе `Delete` у вас есть `previous = current;`.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно интересно читать и вникать в Ваш код.

1. Почему Вы не расширяете class ReplacableLinkedList : LinkedList?
2. Когда у Вас будет LinkedList то вы сможете спокойно пользоваться его методами get, add, insert, ....

Comment: потому что задание звучит, с помощью собственного LinkedList сделать таск :)